# Sending Image as text message with PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, mms

I'm trying to work around the iPhone not having an API in order to send an MMS. I do not want to send a text message from inside the app, I am looking to have it be able to send a text message with an image attached to a certain contact.

I am not very familiar with native iPhone apps so I was going to build the app using PhoneGap and create custom plugins for sending the text message.

The user would find an image/video or something they would want to view on the app, click send to a contact and then normal text message app on the iPhone would pop up with the image already inserted to the body of the message.

Would I be able to write my own plugin for PhoneGap in order to do this operation? If so, what are some good resources to go about learning how to do this?

Thanks, I know this is more of a cry for help on how to do this but after a bunch of research, I can't quite find what I'm exactly looking for.

Comment: You might want to start with looking into the iOS Social.framework and the social plugins for phoneGap. Their implementation is similar to what you are describing, and yes, a plugin could be created to use MFMessageComposeViewController as it were native.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about PhoneGap tbh but I guess where you will fail is this:

Apple did not want you to put photos in the sms app. How do you think you are going to go around this? The only thing I can think of is uploading the image you want to attach to some service like Dropbox and then paste a download link into the sms app.

Comment: But what about using the MFMessageComposeViewController Class to create a plugin for PhoneGap in order to pass the image to the messaging app (the default one)?